# How to remove duplicated dependencies code from webpack bundle?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, webpack-5, webpack-config

I have these local NPM packages:

```
           common-package
           ^          ^
           |          |
father-package       mother-package
           ^          ^
           |          |
            son-package
```

Both `father-package` and `mother-package` import `common-package`, and then `son-package` imports both `father-package` and `mother-package`

The problem here is that the `son-package` bundle duplicates the `common-package` code. The `common-package` has a `User.ts` class and as you can see there are 2 definitions of the `User.ts` class in the output bundle when searching for "class User {":

[image]

My **goal** is to dedupe it. I believe that is possible by tweaking webpack.config.js optimization but i cant figure how.

Here is what I have tried so far:

**son-package webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    plugins:[
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html',
            inject: true,
            filename: './index.html'
        })
    ],
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                commons: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendors',
                    chunks: 'all',
                },
            },
        },
    },
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    target: 'es2017',
    entry: {
        index: './src/Index.ts'
    },
    output: {
        path: `${path.resolve('dist')}`,
        filename: '[name].js',
        library: {
            type: 'module'
        },
        chunkFormat: 'module'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                use:  'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts'],
    }
      
};
```

Should i add the same optimization configuration in `father-package` and `mother-package` to `webpack.config.json` files?

Hope to have explained my problem well. Thanks in advance.

Btw, my node version is v18.11.0 and NPM is 8.19.2 and webpack 5.

Comment: Are you sure there's duplication? Normally in this case only one copy of common-package is compiled but referenced by both. Normally there is nothing you need to do so the answer is simply do nothing. But you could have code that is not normal...

Comment: So far in your question you have no proof that common-package is duplicated.

Comment: @slebetman Thanks for noticing. I updated the question with a screenshot of part of the output bundle